# About the definition of trees for directed graphs in “Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition” by CLRS(Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I am reading “Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition” by CLRS(Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein).

There is a section for trees in Appendix B.5 in this book.
There are definitions of several kinds of trees for undirected graphs in Appendix B.5.

But there is no definition of trees for directed graphs in Appendix B.5(and I think there is no definition in this book) and the authors use trees for directed graphs, for example in Chapter 24 "Single-Source Shortest Paths".

What is ***the definition of trees for directed graphs***?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia article on "Tree (graph theory)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))?  There the term "polytree" and some synonyms are used for directed acyclic graphs (DAG) whose underlying undirected graphs are trees.  DAGs are important objects in the theory of algorithms.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you very much. By the way, I don't like the following definition: A polytree is a directed acyclic graph (DAG) whose underlying undirected graph is a tree. I think "A polytree is a subgraph of a directed graph whose underlying undirected graph is a tree" is a better definition.

Comment: The important point is that an author should define any terms that he or she uses, unless their meanings are sure to be standard for the targeted audience.